# How can container user and host user both have access to same files in volume?

Tags: docker, linux, npm

I'm using Docker namespaces in an effort to allow files created within a volume to be arbitrarily read and written to by both the container user and the host user (please let me know if this is even a valid approach to what I'm trying to do!).

My host username is `aryzing`. So I'm running the docker deamon as

```
dockerd --userns-remap=aryzing
```

The volume maps my host's `~/workspace/app` to the volume's `/usr/src/app`.

From the host system I have no issue modifying the files, but from within the container, I have access errors. Specifically, I'm running NPM's install command from within the container, `npm install`, and it's unable to install the packages due to a permissions error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
```

As per [this post](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/using-docker-with-users-leaves-files-belonging-to-the-subuid-subgid) I've also tried running the container with the `--user` flag, and ran into the same issue.

Any suggestions on how to achive the functionality I'm after?

Answer (score 2):

I was tripping myself up: when I was trying the `--user` flag, I still had `--userns-remap` set. Running the daemon without `--userns-remap` did the trick.